# Create a new user trough AWS ApiGateway secured with Cognito - how to allow access to the users before it is created?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have an API in AWS API gateway secured with AWS-Cognito. In order to use the endpoint the user must to be recognized by Cognito that will return a token.

The question here is related to the CREATE USER process. In order to use this endpoint the user must to exist in the Cognito, then receive the token and use it to connect to the CREATE USER endpoint. But at the moment of the creation of the user in the database (api-endpoint) the user is not created in Cognito and has no permission to get access to the API.

So, how should be the best approach to this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to always use the TOKEN authorizer. API Gateway allows you to configure another type of authorizer: REQUEST.

In that case it's entirely up to you how you want to tell if someone is (or is not) authorized to make a call to your API endpoint.

The `event` will look something like this (taken from AWS documentation):

```json
{
  "type": "REQUEST",
  "methodArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456789012:abcdef123/test/GET/request",
  "resource": "/request",
  "path": "/request",
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "X-AMZ-Date": "20170718T062915Z",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "HeaderAuth1": "headerValue1",
    "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
    "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
    "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
    "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
    "User-Agent": "..."
  },
  "queryStringParameters": {
    "QueryString1": "queryValue1"
  },
  "pathParameters": {},
  "stageVariables": {
    "StageVar1": "stageValue1"
  },
  "requestContext": {
    "path": "/request",
    "accountId": "123456789012",
    "resourceId": "05c7jb",
    "stage": "test",
    "requestId": "...",
    "identity": {
      "apiKey": "...",
      "sourceIp": "...",
      "clientCert": {
        "clientCertPem": "CERT_CONTENT",
        "subjectDN": "www.example.com",
        "issuerDN": "Example issuer",
        "serialNumber": "a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1",
        "validity": {
          "notBefore": "May 28 12:30:02 2019 GMT",
          "notAfter": "Aug  5 09:36:04 2021 GMT"
        }
      }
    },
    "resourcePath": "/request",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "apiId": "abcdef123"
  }
}
```

Then you need to tell API Gateway that it can pass this response through:

```json
{
    "principalId": "any-identifier-you-choose-like-uuid",
    "policyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:111111111111:abcdef/prod/GET/myresource"
        ]
    }
}
```

There is also caching policy involved, but this should be enough for you to start.

Comment: Let me know if I understood. You have create an IAM rule that allow a regular user identified in the`principalId` to invoke a specific endpoint. Then I should use this specific rule attached in the web page that created a user and will invoke the POST user/ endpoint. is it correct?

Comment: There is no IAM role involved here. All you return is a policy document. The principal ID is your own identifier. It can be your user's ID in your own database. So you make a call to API gateway. It then calls your authorizer. It responds with this policy document saying you are authorized to call the mentioned API endpoint. That's it.